# How should I implement ExecuteAsync with RestSharp on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone-7, rest, restsharp

I'm attempting to use the documentation on the [RestSharp GitHub wiki](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) to implement calls to my REST API service but I'm having an issue with the ExecuteAsync method in particular.

Currently my code looks like this for the API class:

```
public class HarooApi
{
    const string BaseUrl = "https://domain.here";

    readonly string _accountSid;
    readonly string _secretKey;

    public HarooApi(string accountSid, string secretKey)
    {
        _accountSid = accountSid;
        _secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
        request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) =>
        {
            return response.Data;
        });
    }
}
```

I'm aware this slightly deviates from what is on the GitHub page but I'm using this with WP7 and believe the example is for C# hence the usage of the ExecuteAsync method.

My problem is with what the ExecuteAsync command should contain. I can't use `return response.Data` because I'm warned:

```
'System.Action<RestSharp.RestResponse<T>,RestSharp.RestRequestAsyncHandle>' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
```

Does anyone have any insight on how to fix this or a tutorial that may assist?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
public class HarooApi
{
    const string BaseUrl = "https://domain.here";

    readonly string _accountSid;
    readonly string _secretKey;

    public HarooApi(string accountSid, string secretKey)
    {
        _accountSid = accountSid;
        _secretKey = secretKey;
    }

    public void ExecuteAndGetContent(RestRequest request, Action<string> callback)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
        request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
        {
            callback(response.Content);
        });
    }

    public void ExecuteAndGetMyClass(RestRequest request, Action<MyClass> callback)
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
        request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        client.ExecuteAsync<MyClass>(request, (response) =>
        {
            callback(response.Data);
        });
    }
}
```

I added two methods, so you can check what you want (string content from the response body, or a deserialized class represented here by `MyClass`)

Comment: Your sample also has the same syntax error and doesn't compile. The second parameter of `ExecuteAsync` is an `Action<RestResponse>` so can cannot use `return` in it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've fixed the sample, please try it now (and please note: the methods are async, so you can't directly return it, unless you use the .NET Async Task)

Comment: Could some help me how to use the ExecuteAndGetMyClass ?

Comment: callback does not exist in current context

Comment: When trying this solution I get:
Error CS1593 Delegate 'Action<IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle>' does not take 1 arguments

Answer (score 50):

Old question but if you are using C# 5 you can have a generic execute class by creating a TaskCompleteSource that resturns a Task of T. Your code could look like this:

```
public Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
        request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response.Data));
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
private async Task DoWork()
    {
        var api = new HarooApi("MyAcoountId", "MySecret");
        var request = new RestRequest();
        var myClass = await api.ExecuteAsync<MyClass>(request);

        // Do something with myClass
    }
```

Comment: I needed a string response for my case. But this line really helped me:
  client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(response.Data));
I wasn't sure how to return the response directly instead of using a callback before and this is the way to go.

If someone wants to use this just swap the respone.Data with response.Content and remove the T from everywhere

Comment: I have to ask - how do you get it past the NotYetExecuted status? Been trying with this sample today and cannot get any results. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 33):

As an alternative (or complement) to the [fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680143/4949005) by [Gusten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725082/gusten). You can use `ExecuteAsync`. This way you do not manually have to handle `TaskCompletionSource`. Note the `async` keyword in the signature.

**Update:**
As of [106.4.0](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/releasenotes.md#10640) `ExecuteTaskAsync` is obsolete. Since [104.2](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/releasenotes.md#1042) you should use `ExecuteAsync` instead:

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
    request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    IRestResponse<T> response = await client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request);
    return response.Data;
}
```

**Old Answer:**

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_accountSid, _secretKey);
    request.AddParameter("AccountSid", _accountSid, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    IRestResponse<T> response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<T>(request); // Now obsolete
    return response.Data;
}
```

Comment: this is the answer I've been looking for...thanks!  Much more straightforward than the other solutions (though not necessarily what the OP was after)

Comment: How to access to `StatusCode` from output of this method?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. The example above doesn't use `StatusCode` at all. Instead of returning `response.Data` you could return `response`. Then you need to change return type to `Task<IRestResponse<T>>`.

Answer (score 7):

Or more precisely like this:

```
    public async Task<IRestResponse<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : class, new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_settingsViewModel.BaseUrl);

        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse<T>>();
        client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, restResponse =>
        {
            if (restResponse.ErrorException != null)
            {
                const string message = "Error retrieving response.";
                throw new ApplicationException(message, restResponse.ErrorException);
            }
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(restResponse);
        });

        return await taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following did the job

```
public async Task<IRestResponse<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : class, new()
{
    var client = new RestClient
    {
        BaseUrl = _baseUrl,
        Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_useraname, _password),
        Timeout = 3000,
    };

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, restResponse =>
    {
        if (restResponse.ErrorException != null)
        {
            const string message = "Error retrieving response.";
            throw new ApplicationException(message, restResponse.ErrorException);
        }
        tcs.SetResult(restResponse.Data);
    });

    return await tcs.Task as IRestResponse<T>;

}
```

Comment: How is this implemented in the function call? is it             `var myclass =  await apiService.ExecuteAsync<MyClass>(request);`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `public static RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsync(this IRestClient client, IRestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse> callback)` has been deprecated, you should look to using `public Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteAsync(IRestRequest request, CancellationToken token = default)` instead.

The following code

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => { callback(response.Content); });
```

Should instead become

```
await client.ExecuteAsync(request).ContinueWith(task => callback(task.Result.Content));
```